# What about storing the like & dislike count in my article table?

Tags: php, sql, database

I developed a like/dislike vote system.

Pretty simple, a vote table where there are article_id, vote_type (-1 or +1)

Two avoid such `SELECT SUM(vote_type) FROM vote WHERE vote_type = +1` I had the idea to store that count in my article table using an Event/Listener system.

What do you think about that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This type of doing things (denormalization) is a very standard practice when performance is much more important than data integrity. So IMHO it's more than OK to do it in your case, as you don't really care if the "like" count for a page becomes slightly off for some reason.

However, you might need to store the likes one-per-row anyway if you want to also save information such as who liked what, timestamps, etc. Which in no way invalidates what I said in paragraph above.

Comment: Well, I may have mis explained, the idea is actually to keep the vote table, but just because the vote count is heavy I'd like to store increment the count. I may run a cron every night to reajust the count if for some reasons it is not correct!

Comment: @JohnT: Then only the first paragraph applies. Go ahead as planned. :)

Comment: Ok thank you! Would it be bad then to have 4 news column in my table? (vote_up, vote_down, selection_up, selection_down) isn't it bad when a table is getting too large (in column number pov I mean)

Comment: @JohnT: Depends on the numbers. If you have 1K articles and 1M votes, you won't notice the extra 16KB or so for the 4 columns.

Answer (score 2):

What ever system you will use the matter will not change.
 You still need to have a table like now with `article_id, vote_type (-1 or +1)`